# What is the most terse alternative to my node.js try/catch?

Tags: node.js, error-handling, try-catch

### Overview

I have a node.js app, which calls out to an external API via HTTP and does a regular expression validation and capture on the content-disposition header value returned in the response header. I currently have it coded as a try/catch block; however, I have read ample sources which seem to shun this approach in general.

### My Issue

My issue is that I cannot quite discern from said aforementioned sources whether *my* particular instance of try/catch is unsafe or potentially error prone, as there are some cases in which try/catch in node.js is appropriate (e.g. json parsing). Is there a better alternative to my try/catch block shown below?

### My Try/Catch Block

```
var parseFileName = function (contentDisposition) {
    "use strict";
    return /filename[^;=\n]*=[\\'"]*((['"]).*?\2|[^;'"\n]*)/g.exec(contentDisposition)[1];
};

try {
    contentDisposition = response.headers["content-disposition"];
    fileName = parseFileName(contentDisposition);
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    return next(new Error("Content Disposition parse failed"));
}
```

### Close

Thanks very much in advance for any insight or help.

Best,

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code allows for an error to be thrown when there's no match for a filename (which would make `/.../.exec()` return `null`, and `null[1]` will throw). That's not really an exceptional situation, it's just lazy return value handling :)

I would probably use something like this myself:

```
let parseFileName = function (contentDisposition) {
  "use strict";
  let match = /filename[^;=\n]*=[\\'"]*((['"]).*?\2|[^;'"\n]*)/g.exec(contentDisposition);
  return match ? match[1] : null;
};

let contentDisposition = response.headers["content-disposition"];
let fileName = parseFileName(contentDisposition);
if (! fileName) {
  return next(new Error("Content Disposition parse failed"));
}
```

It has the added advantage that not all calls to `parseFileName` (might there be more) are required to use `try/catch`.

Comment: Ah ok, this makes good sense. I'll need to read more about the topic overall; however, your solution certainly makes sense to me in this context. Thanks so much!